# Can't get a way to read the property "user" in class "App\Entity\User"

Tags: forms, symfony

I made a form so that when a user is selected, his role changes from ["ROLE_USER"] to ["ROLE_ADMIN"]. When form is submitted, I have the following error : `Can't get a way to read the property "user" in class "App\Entity\User".`

I understand it must come the fact there is no such field named **user** in the User class, but I don't know with which field I can replace **user**. I already tried **name** or **roles**, but it doesn't work either with them.

How can I select a user and simply change his role ?

**AdminType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Admin;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class AdminType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->andWhere('u.roles LIKE :role')
                        ->setParameter('role', '["ROLE_USER"]')
                        ->orderBy('u.firstname', 'ASC');
                },
                'placeholder' => 'J\'ajoute un administrateur',
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Form\Admin\AdminType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/admin/list', name: 'admin')]
    public function admin(
        Request $request, 
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface
    ){   
        $admins = $userRepository->admin();
        
        $form = $this->createForm(AdminType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->get('user')->getData();
            $user->setRoles(["ROLE_ADMIN"]);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($user);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('admin/user/admin.html.twig', [
            'admins' => $admins,
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

remove `'data_type' => User::class` from `configureOptions` in your `AdminType` form.

#### Explanation

Setting the `data_type` of the form to the `User` entity will cause Symfony to try to create a `User` object and set its `user` Property to the value in the form's `user` field (which you get via `$form->get('user')`). That's why the error message tells you, that it can't find a way to read (to then overwrite) the property `user` on the `User` class.

Removing the `data_type` will then mean, that the form's data type is just an array (the default), you could also explicitly set `null`.

If the form's data type is an array, it'll just set the `user` key in that array.

Since your form's `user` field is of type `EntityType`, with a given class, it already ensures that the form's `user` field's value must be of that class (the `User` entity). And since you only want to *select* a user, to then add a role, I assume that the form doesn't need the User `data_type`.

Comment: Brillant ! It's working properly now. Thank you Jakumi.